# How to trigger a Plugin in the Joomla 4

Tags: plugins, joomla, joomla4

I am facing while calling plugin in joomla 4

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('search');
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
```

this is not working joomla 4, this thing works fine  in joomla 3

Can anone suggest me the correct syntax for that

Comment: You're facing what?